# Как в Ansible обработать составную переменную?

Tags: ansible

[третий день знакомства с ansible :)]

Не могу сообразить, как можно обработать переменную типа такой

```
vars:
  - testvar:
      - category1:
           - item1
           - item2
      - category2:
           - item1
           - item2
           - item3
```

Теперь, например, я в одном таске хочу вывести поочередно category1 и category2, а в другом поочередно список item-ов для каждой категории.

Такая конструкция выводит все разом

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ testvar }}"
```

Такая, можно сказать работает, но это... не оптимально

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - category1
    - category2
```